# GTA 5 disc 2 "Play disc" is unreadable

Tags: xbox-360, grand-theft-auto-v

Guys I request to please read the question first before jumping to the conclusion that the play disc must NOT be installed.

I got a brand new Xbox 360 Slim 4 GB, and a new GTA 5 game.

The first disc installed perfectly on a pen drive but the second disc is unreadable. Sometimes it runs, many times it doesnt.

With so many users getting the same problem, I really dont think there is some problem with my Xbox. But if it is, I would not mind giving it to the service center.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 3):

A certain percentage of discs (typically very small) will be defective right out of the box. The cause of this can be as simple as 0.001" variation on when the signature should be, caused by a piece of dust, or a light breeze, during manufacturing.

You should return the game at once to where you bought it. They will give you a new one.

Comment: i tried to return my copy at Media Markt (The netherlands), but they did not accept it. Personnel of Media Markt said: "You should buy a new copy of GTA V or go to Microsoft or Rockstar Games with this problem", weird. Anyway, i'm not happy with this, so i contacted Microsoft but they said that it was completely Rockstar Games' problem, so i contacted Rockstar Games but i'm still waiting for a reply right now....

Comment: I guess whatever happens you probably shouldn't buy another copy from those guys, since they sound like real d-bags.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what happened to my disc. There was a slight crack on the disc that extended from the center hole of the disc, up a centimeter or two, just barely going into the actual disc part. The still ran perfectly, but recently I discovered something almost like an air bubble or something around that crack, and the game won't run at all. It will not recognize the disc.
As for your problem, GTAV requires a minimum of 8GB's to run, as the entire install takes a little over 7GB's. Disc one probably just didn't install all the way or something.

Answer (score 0):

It sometimes lets me play online but if I go to do a job it would lag out and say unreadable disk or if I want to play with my friends it would do the same thing so what I did was I deleted everything and reinstalled it and know it's working better meaning it lets me play longer